# git port - network requirement

Tags: git, networking, push

While connected to my office network, I always not be able to run git push. It seems there is network setting issue. Any advice how to troubleshoot the issue or what request shall I convey to network team?

Comment: Note: with Git 2.6 (Q3 2015), `GIT_TRACE_PACKFILE` can help debug too. See [my answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32039039/6309)

Answer (score 0):

You can try running with a couple options set:

```
$ GIT_TRACE=2 git push
```

This will cause extra debugging information to be emitted and may be useful.  If you're using an HTTP connection to your repository, you could try:

```
$ GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1 git push
```

Or, you can use `GIT_TRACE_PACKET` to get more information about the on-the-wire transfer:

```
$ GIT_TRACE_PACKET=1 git push
```

It will stop tracing packets once it sees a pack transfer starting, but it may help provide more information about the underlying cause.

You can combine the options as well.  This is probably the most useful invocation to start with:

```
$ GIT_TRACE=2 GIT_TRACE_PACKET=1 git push
```

Answer (score 0):

Git 2.6+  (Q3 2015) will propose an extension to the existing `GIT_TRACE_PACKET` debugging option.

See [commit 3235983](https://github.com/git/git/commit/323598387d900263c4980b43b8a96c43cdd7b6c7) (16 Jun 2015), and [commit d6d1a75](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d6d1a75e51cf90650ac6e2cdcd8d108324b6fdb9), [commit f3612ac](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f3612acb9302fc9332958b77c5ca5fc05cacb029) (12 Jun 2015) by [Jeff King (`peff`)](https://github.com/peff).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 0b9ce18](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0b9ce18ede8343116f4e5f008c05169f69cafc07), 03 Aug 2015)</sup>

> ## `pkt-line`: support tracing verbatim pack contents
>
> When debugging the pack protocol, it is sometimes useful to store the verbatim pack that we sent or received on the wire. Looking at the on-disk result is often not helpful for a few reasons:
>
> 1. If the operation is a clone, we destroy the repo on failure, leaving nothing on disk.
> 2. If the pack is small, we unpack it immediately, and the full pack never hits the disk.
> 3. If we feed the pack to "`index-pack --fix-thin`", the resulting pack has the extra delta bases added to it.
>
> We already have a `GIT_TRACE_PACKET` mechanism for tracing packets.
>   Let's **extend it with `GIT_TRACE_PACKFILE` to dump the verbatim packfile**.